# Microsoft Teams Tabs

Tags: microsoft-teams

While configuring tabs in ms teams im getting the following error,

**Unable to save configuration for "my tab" tab**

On inspecting network , 
https://apac.ng.msg.teams.microsoft.com/v1/threads/19%3Afbee865537ce40fe86e34570961dc044%40thread.skype/properties?name=tab%3A%3A2667288576
Request Method: PUT

this request have returned the following response,

{"errorCode":287,"message":"The size of this request is too large."}

Cant find any documentation related to this.

Can anyone help 
Thanks in Advance .

Comment: Could you please share your App manifest?

Comment: How many tabs are configured in your channel?

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved .Issue is that I was using manifest and schema version 1.3 which seems to be unstable .When i switched it to 1.2 it worked fine .
Thanks !

Comment: This is yet to release so I cant share the file here. one more issue . In IE 11 on calling microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate childwindow is got as null and it calls failure handler .It works fine for Chrome.
IN MicrosoftTeams.js in function OpenAuthenticationWindow :

childWindow = currentWindow.open(link.href, "_blank", "toolbar=no, location=yes, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, top=" +
                top +
                ", left=" +
                left +
                ", width=" +
                width +
                ", height=" +
                height);

Comment: Above was due to proxy .

Comment: This definitely not an issue with Manifest version. Could you please confirm with v1.3 once?

Comment: {"errorCode":287,"message":"The size of this request is too large."}

This one is not due to 1.3 ?

Comment: Could you please try once again with v1.3 and let us know if you see the issue? Also, How many tabs are configured in your channel?